# Facebook development - login url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm building facebook app. I need to get some permissions. I use php sdk.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that LOGIN URL opens in **popup** mode and some browsers doesn't allow that action.

Can you tell what can I do in this case?

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$config = array(
  'appId' => '123456789',
  'secret' => '123456789',
  'fileUpload' => true,
  'allowSignedRequest' => false 
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id) {
   try {
      include "some.php";
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
   } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload', 'scope' => 'user_likes', ));
      header ("Location: $login_url");
      error_log($e->getType());
      error_log($e->getMessage());
   }   
} else {
   $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload', 'scope' => 'user_likes', ));
   header ("Location: $login_url");
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I mean, I used your code and this is not opening in a popup in my case..

Comment: There is no reason why a `Location` header should have anything to do with popups. // And you’re overwriting the `scope` key in the array that you pass to `getLoginUrl` here … some _basic_ knowledge of PHP before using any APIs would be helpful.