# Facebook development - post link with photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm building an app for facebook. I need to post some link, standard code works correctly:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
    array(
      'link' => 'Mylink',
      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!',
```

But I need to attach the photo also. It works if photo is on the link I post, but I don't want that photo to appear on that page.

Is there any way?

Comment: I hid the image on the page using technique 1px*1px.. it works, but the image is not dinamic. I mean, I changed the image, but facebook posts the link with old one.. Is there any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: What about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796300/facebook-development-login-url? Pls dont leave the questions just like that, either respond to the comments or post an answer if you have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a parameter, `picture` to while making the call-

```
 array(
   'link' => 'Mylink',
   'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!',
   'picture' => '{image-link}'
```